Threebox , Mapbox: FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
I want to use threebox to display object on mapbox.
My mapbox works correctly. When i add
 ngOnInit() {
 mapboxgl!.accessToken = 'token';
 this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: this.style,
  zoom: 13,
  pitch: 45,
  center: [this.lng, this.lat]
 });
 // Add map controls

 const tb = new Threebox(
      this.map,
      this.map.getCanvas().getContext('webgl'), //get the context from Mapbox
      { defaultLights: true }
    );
..
}

Adding
const tb = new Threebox(this.map,this.map.getCanvas().getContext('webgl'),{ defaultLights: true } );
gives the error.
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
1: 00007FF7C15D07BF node_api_throw_syntax_error+175823
If i remove that const tb line the error is gone. So the error is in that line.
The error is related to memory leak.
I have done
node --max_old_space_size=8384 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve 
But the error remains
